# Opacity not working on website but working on jsfiddle....help please

Tags: html, css

On the right hand side I have social media icons. When you scroll over one, the others are supposed to disappear and the one you are hovering over is supposed to stay. This works on jsfiddle but not on my page.

Also, when you hover the name of the icon is supposed to display above it. It does but it is very jittery, however in jsfiddle it works properly...

Any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/gvqGk/32/

The website is at

http://lolabellas.tumblr.com

Thanks so much!

```
.social { list-style:none;margin:0; padding:0;}

.social li { display:inline; float:left;}
.social li a { display:block;width:32px; height:32px; position:relative; text-     decoration:none; padding-right:-5px}
.social li a strong { font-weight:normal; position:absolute; left:30px; top:-1px;   color:#fff; padding:3px; z-index:9999;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
-moz-border-radius:3px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); -webkit-border-radius:3px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border-radius:3px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

}

​

```
 /* SOCIAL ICONS - CSS3 */
 #css3:hover li { opacity:0.2; }

 #css3 li { -webkit-transition-property: opacity; -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
 -moz-transition-property: opacity; -moz-transition-duration: 500ms; }
  #css3 li a strong { opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition-property: opacity, top; -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
 -moz-transition-property: opacity, top; -moz-transition-duration: 300ms; }

 #css3 li:hover { opacity:1; }
 #css3 li:hover a strong { opacity:1; top:-30px; }


 li.facebook{background:url("http://static.tumblr.com/4aqmjkd/kVVm77wsy/facebook-32x32.png" ) no-repeat; width:32px; height:32px;}

 li.twitter {background:url("http://static.tumblr.com/4aqmjkd/yllm77x0x/twitter-32x32.png") no-repeat; width:32px; height:32px;}

 li.flickr {background:url("http://static.tumblr.com/4aqmjkd/ZzZm77wzi/flickr-32x32.png") no-repeat; width:32px; height:32px;}

 li.pintrest {background:url("http://static.tumblr.com/4aqmjkd/9RNm77x0c/pintrest__32_x_32.png") no-repeat; width:32px; height:32px;}

 li.etsy {background:url("http://static.tumblr.com/4aqmjkd/lWXm77wyk/etsy_32_x_32.png") no-repeat; width:32px; height:32px;}


 li.contact {background:url("http://static.tumblr.com/4aqmjkd/f5om77wxr/email_32_x_32.png") no-repeat; width:32px; height:32px;}


 <ul class="social" id="css3">
                        <li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/lolabellasco" target="_blank"><strong>Facebook</strong></a></li>
                        <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/lolabellasco" target="_blank"><strong>Twitter</strong></a></li>


                        <li class="flickr"><a href="http://www.flickr.com" target="_blank"><strong>Flickr</strong></a></li>
                        <li class="pintrest"><a href="http://pinterest.com/lolabellas/" target="_blank"><strong>Pintrest</strong></a></li>
                        <li class="etsy"><a href="http://lolabellas.etsy.com" target="_blank"><strong>Etsy</strong></a></li>

                        <li class="contact"><a href="mailto:lolabellasetsy@gmail.com"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>


                        </ul>
```

Comment: Can you please also post the *relevant* code that displays the problem in this question? That way the question might be useful to future users as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gvqGk/33/   Even with all of the HTML that needs to be fixed the hover opacity works...thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's causing the specific hover issue, but having two conflicting `<!DOCTYPE>`s, a `<script>` outside the `<head>/<body>` areas, a conditional comment that completely breaks IE due to the text marking the end of the head and starting the body with most of the head still to come... probably don't help.

Conversely, the Fiddle lacks all of the above bollocks and works just fine. I would suggest tidying up your HTML before wondering why things don't work.

Comment: Just looked at the HTML as well. There is ALOT of things that need sorting.

Answer (score 1):

In what browsers are you testing this?

Another answer refers to the `<!DOCTYPE>` HTML tag. You must understand the importance of this tag. Any web browser will open .HTML or .HTM document, but the only way the browser actually knows the author's intended format of the file is to include this `<!DOCTYPE>` tag. Starting out, I did not realize this fact.

So who cares? Well, it matters whether the browser is identifying your file as HTML4, `transitional` XHTML, `strict` HTML5, and so on. For instance, a browser might automatically identify documents which lack a `<!DOCTYPE>` as HTML4 (because that attribute did not exist until later). I believe this means that the browser would ignore CSS formatting.

In short, learn what HTML doctypes are and make sure to use one that supports most or all of what you're trying to use. Hopefully, you can find a happy medium with one of the doctype options, but you may very well have to alter some of your code. Good luck!

EDIT: You have to test whatever you're developing in all of the major browsers. To be specific, the reason for this is that each browser has behavior/interpretation differences. You will often be sorely disappointed if you forget to test in multiple browsers during an hour of coding. LoL it's not fun to find out your code is broken in 3 out of 5 browsers, and that it would have been much easier to fix as you were first writing it an hour ago. These are words to code by: test as you go, and test widely.

Comment: I'm using safari 5.1... what doctype would you recommend?

Comment: Personally, I recommend strict HTML5. It builds character. ;-) make sure to validate your HTML5 formatting, using an HTML5 validator. I recommend this one: http://validator.w3.org/  Come to think of it, I don't know of any other ones.

Comment: Also, you can't just test in Safari. You have to test in every one of the major browsers (unless you'd rather forget about the majority of the market share of browsers).

Answer (score 0):

@ Hi, this should help. Redefine this style:

```css
.social li a strong { top:-30px !important; left:-10px !important; }
```